# Cant create the DB with TPH mode.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing MVC application.
I am trying to build the project by model first technique. 
I have created the three class.

1. Company - Base/Parent class.
2. Customer - Child class inherited from Company class.
3. Party class - Child class inherited from Company class.

now while generating the DB , it creates three separate tables , which I dont want. 
I want to create the single table for these entities.

I think VS 2012 dont support TPH.

What to do ?

Comment: Is your `Company` class abstract?

Comment: Yes, Company is a abstract class...

Answer (score 0):

You need a customization in the process of building the model. You do that overriding the `OnModelCreating` method Like this:

```
public class Company
{
    // need this property has value C to customer or P to party.
    public char CustomerOrParty { get; set; }

    // other properties.
    // ...
}

public class Customer : Company
{
    // code
}

public class Party : Company
{
    // code
}

public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Map<Customer>(m => m.Requires("CustomerOrParty").HasValue('C'))
            .Map<Party>(m => m.Requires("CustomerOrParty").HasValue('P'));
    }
}
```

You can see a tutorial in here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/17/code-first-ef-4-1-table-per-hierarchy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can map your model to tables by overriding OnModelCreating.

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Party> Parties{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .ToTable("Company);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .ToTable("Company);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Party>()
            .ToTable("Company);
    }
}
```